# From OO to functional programming at 10,000 feet

Tags: haskell, f#, functional-programming

I have been using f# and Haskell to learn functional programming for a while now. Until I can get f# approved at our company I must still use c#. I am still trying however to stay in the functional style as I have noticed several benefits.

Here is a typical problem.

1. There is a key-set table in the
   database with 3 keys (6.5 million
   rows)
2. There are 4 other supporting
   tables of small to medium size.
3. There are complex formulas based on several inputs.

I have to use data from all of the above to calculate a value and associate it with each key-set row and send it back to the database. There is a lot of lookups to the other 4 tables. For performance sake it is all done in memory.

I know exactly how I would do the in OO with static dictionaries, object models, strategy patterns and so forth but in a functional way I cannot get rid of the bad smell of using some of these constructs.

I am currently making the following assumptions for a functional solution.

1. Static dictionaries are bad. It seems the function could have side affects.
2. I need an Calculate function the takes an immutable object(s) and returns an immutable object with the three keys and the calculated value. Inside this function there could be another function in the same style.
3. Traditional OO patterns are probably not going to work.

How would you design this at a high level?

Am I wrong? Have I missed anything?

Answer (score 6):

No, you are not not wrong. Both OOP and functional programming have their benefits and their drawbacks.

A developer needs tho know how and when to use each development style. It's fortunate that C# supports in a way both development styles.

In my opinion, and I use both functional and oop programming styles on a daily bases, oop is best when dealing with complex interactions and inter dependencies between various abstract artifacts (entities, nouns etc. ). Functional programming is best used when dealing with algorithms, data transformations etc. e.g. situations where the complexity of statements needed to solve a given problem is great.

I generally use object oriented programming on my domain (entities, aggregates, value objects, repositories and events) and reserve functional programming for my service objects.

Most of the the time it comes to a smell, or feeling which is best, since in software development aren't clear cut cases either way, and experience and practice often is the best judge for a given choice.

Answer (score 2):

If your looking for speed you may want to consider the underlying data structures your using. Dictionary<> in C# is a hash table while SortedDictionary<> in C# is a binary search tree.

F# and Haskell both do a good job of representing tree data structures.  You may want to consider using a more specific data structure over the default ones C# provides.

At a high level I would figure out what performance characteristics your formulas display and compare them to different data structures (wikipedia is a good source if you need a refresher).  Once you figure out what data structures to use then I'd worry about what implementations to use.

Comment: Dunno about C#, but a properly implemented hash table does not have slow lookups.  To maintain lookup speed, inserts occasionally have to rehash the entire table, however.  (But this is not a big deal; even BerkeleyDB does this for its on-disk hashes.)

The advantage of a tree over a hash table is reference locality; if you are iterating over a chunk of the table "in order", it is easy to prefetch the "next" nodes.

Comment: I removed my comments about what's faster or slower.  There are many different advantages and disadvantages for hash tables vs binary trees depending on how you use them.  C# Dictionary<> does indeed have a fast lookup time.  "average asymptotic running time for adding, removing, and searching the hashtable using probing is constant time, O(1)" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379571(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

> How would you design this at a high level?

Basically, you use higher-order functions to factor the work into reusable components with low syntactic overhead. Then you might like to migrate from imperative data structures to purely functional data structures (purely functional computation wrapped in side effects for IO like database writes). Finally, you might even track side effects (completely purely functional).

As a rough guide, these three gradations to complete purity are seen firstly in Lisp (largely impure), Standard ML (much heavier use of purely functional data structures) and Haskell (complete purity).

I cannot give more specifics without knowing the exact problem but you can rest assured many people are doing this on a daily basis now and it works extremely well.

Answer (score 0):

Functional programming in an OO language tends to be wrong.  It produces overly verbose code that doesn't perform well and is more error prone (such as writing deeply recursive functions in a language that doesn't support tail calls.)

> Blockquote 1. Static dictionaries are bad. It seems the function could have side affects.

Either it does or does not have side effects.  A static dictionary can be a good way to implement memoization in an OO language.

> Blockquote 3. Traditional OO patterns are probably not going to work.

OO patterns work well in an OO language trying to shoe horn FP techniques into a OO language will produce verbose and brittle code.  It is rather a lot like trying to use a screw driver with hammer techniques sure it produces a result but there are better ways.  Try to use your tools in the best way possible. Certain FP techniques can be useful but completely ignoring the language isn't going to make for good quality code.

Comment: Depends on the OO language in question. C# does a pretty good job with functional techniques. And some things can be done in a fairly functional way in more painfully inflexible OO languages like Java, but there's certainly a fair amount of cognitive friction in that case.

Comment: If you end up trying to do something functional and are in the Java environment, it's probably best to do it in Clojure.  While technically a Lisp and not an ML based language, it can be made to work with Java applications (generates JVM bytecode) and support functional style development.

Comment: C# falls flat on many functional techniques. Extremely limited type inference is just a dealbreaker. Try writing out the type of a function that uses several generic parameters, such as a dictionary of functions. Ouch.

Comment: @MichaelGG C# FP has problems, but I've never seen that as being one of them. I find that IntelliSense ends up making me more or less as productive as type inference half the time anyway. The other half is somewhat small.